# "Connecting" SDL_Surface to shared_ptr

Tags: c++, sdl, shared-ptr

I'd like to know how can I connect SDL_Surface* with shared_ptr?
I need to call `SDL_FreeSurface(SDL_Surface*)` before I delete `SDL_Surface`. How can I "modify deletion process" in shared_ptr?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just pass SDL_FreeSurface to the constructor:

```
std::shared_ptr<SDL_Surface> shared_surf(SDL_LoadBMP("foo.bmp"), SDL_FreeSurface);
```

Just be sure you don't do this with the pointer returned by `SDL_SetVideoMode` or `SDL_GetVideoSurface`.

Comment: Why shouldn't you do this with these? (SDL_SetVideoMode etc..)

Comment: @user1511417: As per [the documentation](http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdlsetvideomode.html). *"The surface returned is freed by SDL_Quit() and should nt be freed by the caller."*